# Java TCP Client Server Hangs Up?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, network-programming, serversocket

I am currently having difficulty understanding why my code is not working. I've included my client and server code below. I've figured out that my problem happens somewhere in the while loops but I'm not sure how to fix it so that it doesn't get stuck. I've searched around the forum for a while and some said adding a newline character would fix it, but I'm still having trouble.

My main question is how can I avoid the process from getting stuck and not communicating properly. Can anybody out there point me in the right direction?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


public class My_Client {

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

    Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 5555);

    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( 
            s.getInputStream()));

    PrintStream w = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());

    w.print("hello world");
    w.print('\n');

    String line;

    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Received: " + line);

        //System.out.println("Error");
    }
    w.close();
}
}

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

-----------------------------------------------------------------
public class My_Server {

private static final int PORT = 5555;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(PORT); 
        System.out.println("Server Socket Created");

        while (true) {

            System.out.println("Waiting on connection");
            Socket cs = ss.accept(); 
            System.out.println("Client connected");

            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( 
                    cs.getInputStream()));
            PrintStream w = new PrintStream(cs.getOutputStream());

            String line;

            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                w.print(line + "!!!!");  
                w.print('\n');
            }

            System.out.println("Client disconnected");
            r.close();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

   }

 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Server/client not sending or receiving data through socket \[Java\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21199644/server-client-not-sending-or-receiving-data-through-socket-java) or any number of others. You need the `flush()` if you're not using `println()`

Comment: I don't use PrintWriter though. How is that a duplicate? Do you know if this applies to my problem directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ends are reading until EOS and neither is closing until after that. So you have a classic deadlock. You need to rethink your application protocol.

You *also* need to tell your `PrintStream` or `PrintWriter` to autoflush, or else call `flush()` yourself, but this is a relatively minor matter compared to the mistake above.

Comment: So after looking through the answers someone (Sanjeev) suggested I write a string "[END]" from the client side and check for this in the server to end the loop and this works. Is this the appropriate way to handle this issue? I can see how having the two sides read at the same time could cause a problem, but am wondering if that is the right way to solve this issue or is it a hack?

Comment: It will work but it isn't necessary. You can just shutdown the socket for output instead of sending a specific application protocol message. That will cause the peer's `readLine()` method to return `null,` and away you go.

Answer (score 1):

Check the comments

And be sure that you get `Client Connected` on console of server side

```
CLIENT SIDE
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.PrintStream;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;


    public class My_Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 5555);

        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( 
                s.getInputStream()));

        PrintStream w = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());

        w.print("hello world");
        w.print("\n"); // enter new line
        w.flush();// flush the outputstream
        String line;

        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Received: " + line);

            //System.out.println("Error");
        }
        w.close();
    }
    }
    SERVER SIDE
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.PrintStream;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;

    public class My_Server {

    private static final int PORT = 5555;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(PORT); 
            System.out.println("Server Socket Created");

            while (true) {

                System.out.println("Waiting on connection");
                Socket cs = ss.accept(); 
                System.out.println("Client connected");

                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( 
                        cs.getInputStream()));
                PrintStream w = new PrintStream(cs.getOutputStream());

                String line;

                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    w.print(line + "!!!!");  
                    w.print("\n");// entering new line
                }

                System.out.println("Client disconnected");
                r.close();
                w.close();// close w
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

       }

     }
```

Comment: I tried flushing the output stream and adding the w.close(), but I'm still getting stuck. The program never reaches the w.close() and never exits the loop.

Comment: Where you stuck ? Server side loop or client side loop?

Comment: I'm not sure. How can I determine this? I tried putting a string within the loops to see if there is an infinite loop somewhere but there is no infinite loop which is why it's confusing. It like the program just stops all together

Comment: Do you got `Client connected` printed on server side.

Comment: Yes, the client is connected

Comment: Now ask `@EJP`.. Only `EJP` can help.

Comment: Or Use `BufferedWriter` instead  of `PrintWriter`

Answer (score 1):

You should use autoflush on your PrintWriters like this:

```
PrintStream w = new PrintStream(cs.getOutputStream(),true);
```

You can setup a PROTOCOL to end the communication something like this:

In your client:

`w.println("[END]")`;

In your server:

```
 while (!(line = r.readLine()).equals("[END]")) {
```

Hope this helps: